# How to look for values with % in a column and then sum them up and place it in an empty row?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is any method that could detect a column with %? After that, sum the rows that have the %?

For example, in the following, i have a picture, Column B -D has values that contents %. The total % in B will be 130%, C will be 105%, D will be 90%. The total will be place at the subsequent empty row, for this particular example, will be row 8. I need the row to be flexible as it may end up more than 8.

[image]

I hope someone understands what i'm trying to convey here. What i'm trying to do is to look for the % and sum them up, the total will be placed at the subsequent empty row.

Comment: Does cell B3, for example, contain the text string "30%" or does it contain the number .03 formatted as a percentage?  Is cell B1, a number formatted as General?

Comment: @TonyDallimore, hi... for B3 it is a number that have .03 format as a percentage. As for B1, yes it is as general

Comment: If there is a worksheet function that will isolate values with a particular format, I do not know what it is.  For a VBA solution you need to look at `Cells(Row, Column).NumberFormat` which is a read/write value defining the format of a cell.  I would guess your cells are all formatted as "0%"; certainly the last character will be a percentage.  You want to sum all cells in a column for which `Right(Cells(Row, Column).NumberFormat, 1) = "%"`.

Comment: Thank you for deleting your other question.  Your other question included some VBA and said you did not know how to identify the percentage cells.  Does my previous comment include all the help you need?

Comment: if its possible maybe u can write it out as an answer? i have tried your code, there was a run time error 1004. my other question was to look for names in column A and identify those with %, unfortunately, i just cant get it to work, so i thought maybe i can look for % instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the follow-up question about percentages in column 1.  The following is my solution to your original question.  It creates a row below any existing rows containing the total of any percentages in the column.  I have formatted the values and have coloured then blue to show how.  I have included comments saying what I am doing but not explaining why a statement does what it does.  Try VBA Help first then come back with any questions.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SumPercentages()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColCrntMax As Long
  Dim ColMax As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrntMax As Long
  Dim RowSum As Long
  Dim TotalPerc As Double

  With Sheets("Sheet1")      ' Replace with name of your sheet

     ' Find the last used row plus one as the row on which to place
     ' the totals.  Warning, this statement will throw an error if
     ' there is a value on the last possible row.
     RowSum = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

     ' Find the last used column
     ColMax = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

     ' Examine every used column
     For ColCrnt = 1 To ColMax

       ' Find the last used row in this column
       RowCrntMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColCrnt).End(xlUp).Row

       TotalPerc = 0

       ' Examine each row of this column
       For RowCrnt = 1 To RowCrntMax
         If Right(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).NumberFormat, 1) = "%" Then
           TotalPerc = TotalPerc + Val(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value)
         End If
       Next

       ' Save the value, format as percentage, colour blue
       With .Cells(RowSum, ColCrnt)
         .Value = TotalPerc
         .NumberFormat = "0%"
         .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
       End With

     Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It is easy when you know how.  I have shown you how to play with number formats and the font colour.  Try to learn something every day and soon you will be an expert helping newbies.  Best wishes for your future programming.